# ASP.NET WebApi custom route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple Controller that is returning thumbnails, it is defined like:

```
public class ThumbnailsController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, I can access image using url `http://site.com/api/Thumbnails/mylogin`

But I would like to modify this method like so:

```
public class ThumbnailsController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string login="", int size=64)
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

Idea is to be able to call:
- `http://site.com/api/Thumbnails/` - this will return current logged in user picture in default (64x64) size
- `http://site.com/api/Thumbnails/mylogin` - this will return mylogin user picture in default (64x64) size
- `http://site.com/api/Thumbnails/mylogin/128` - this will return mylogin user picture in 128x128 size

My problem are routes, default route works with my unchanged method, but how should I change the default to get this working?

I will also have other Api Controllers but only this one should have custom route.

Here is my attempt, but it isn't working.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Thumbnails",
            routeTemplate: "api/thumbnails/{login}/{size}",
            defaults: new {controller="Thumbnails", action="Get", login = RouteParameter.Optional, size = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

**EDIT**
This is my Controller with test method:

```
public class ThumbnailsController : ApiController
{
    public string Get(string login="", int size=64)
    {
        return string.Format("login: {0}, size: {1}", login, size);
    }
}
```

and here is my RouteConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Thumbnails",
            routeTemplate: "api/Thumbnails/{login}/{size}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Thumbnails" , login = RouteParameter.Optional, size = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you declare your custom route before the default route in the WebApiConfig.
EDIT:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Thumbnails",
    routeTemplate: "api/Thumbnails/{login}/{size}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Thumbnails", action = "Get", 
        login = RouteParameter.Optional, size = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: I didn't declare default route, just this, as for now I have only this Web API controller

Comment: I've replicated your code and everything appears to be working here. Are you getting an error message or are your calls just not hitting the controller?

Comment: My parameters aren't passed to method, it is getting defaults. I'll modify my question and I'll add test method

Comment: Your custom api route should be declared in the WebApiConfig and NOT the RouteConfig. Also as previously stated, it needs to be the first route declared (i.e. BEFORE the default route that is automatically added).

Answer (score 1):

The custom route should be before the default one
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

```
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Thumbnails",
        routeTemplate: "api/Thumbnails/{login}/{size}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Thumbnails" , login = RouteParameter.Optional, size = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        );
}
```

And try to change the type of the "size" to nullable integer:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string login = null, int? size = 64)
```

Comment: Thanks for help, It's shame that I cant make more that one answer as correct, but @Jonny's comment about route declaration solved my problem.